# the Armenian capital Yerevan or Armenian capital Yerevan

Tags: articles

Example (news story, [Russia warns against "colour revolution" in Armenia](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/russia-warns-against-colour-revolution-121555748.html)):

> Large crowds of mostly young people have been protesting in **the Armenian capital Yerevan** for more than 10 days, demanding the government scrap plans to raise the price of electricity for households.

Is it possible to say *Armenian capital Yerevan* without the article in this situation?

Comment: "...in the Armenian capital, Yerevan. . ."  Or   "...in Yerevan, the Armenian capital . . ."

Comment: The short story is this boils down to the uniqueness of the *capital*. A country, nation, state, province, etc, can have only *one* capital, by definition, and so the usual rule of English articles for unique objects applies: use *the*. The name Yerevan is just a red herring.

Comment: @Dan - It's not really a uniqueness thing at all. Consider: "Protesters marched in the town of Springfield" – we need the article there. To say "Protesters marched in town of Springfield" would sound off.

Comment: @DanBron If you want to get technical about it, South Africa, the Netherlands, and Bolivia have multiple national capitals, and probably other countries as well, and that is not even counting situations like Israel or Taiwan.

Comment: As far as I know, one country, one capital. I just do not see how one can even argue with that. I agree with Brian Hitchcock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the" is required as this sentence is referring to a specific town - rather than one of a number of possible towns.

So no, it is **not** correct to say:

> *young people have been protesting in Armenian capital Yerevan for more than 10 days

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that the answer to this question has already been accepted, to me, the combination  "Armenian/French/Italian/Russian capital", plus the name of the city, ***with or without*** "the "article before the adjective of nationality, sounds ungrammatical. Since you're asking about the use of the articles, I'd suggest the ***"the…of…***" pattern:

> Young people have been protesting in Yerevan, *the capital of Armenia*,
>   for more than 10 days.
>
> In Yerevan,  *the capital of Armenia*, young people have been protesting
>   for more than 10 days.

The other variants may be:

> In Armenia's capital, Yerevan, young people have been protesting for
>   more than 10 days
>
> For more than 10 days, young people of Armenia have been protesting in
>   its capital, Yerevan.